# Accessing .zsh set variable from php

Tags: php

```
php 8.1
Mac OS Monterey
```

I have the following in my .zshrc:

```
export APP_API_KEY='xxxxxxxx'
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
```

My code is:

```
$app_key = getenv("APP_API_KEY");
$path = getenv("PATH");
echo $app_key."</br>";
echo $path."</br>";
```

And what I get is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I tried a number of other environment variables set through the .zshrc file, but only the PATH environment variable works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you run the PHP script from zsh? If not, then it is another environment.

Comment: I am running it from the IDE, so not sure. As in the IDE (PhpStorm) creates its own web server, but it's supposed to be running using the local environment.

Comment: When using a run script, you can add them there. https://ibb.co/mXrXFsk